# Manually buffering CAMetalDrawable frames without tearing

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, metal, metalkit

I've been trying to implement manual double buffering on macOS with MetalKit, but I can't seem to avoid tearing artifacts.

I initially tried following the standard examples with vsync enabled, but noticed that frame latencies tend to accumulate over time (I'm not certain why this is). As a result, I've resorted to disabling display synchronization and timing rendering frames with `CVDisplayLink`.

According to Apple's documentation, the `displaySyncEnabled` property on `CAMetalLayer` toggles "whether the layer synchronizes its updates to the display’s refresh rate." When this is set to `NO`, rendering frames tends to result in tearing, which is expected behavior.

In order to combat this, I tried to implement a manual double buffer, where each frame presents the previous drawable to the screen. My thinking is that because the drawable was rendered last frame, presenting it at the start of the CVDisplayLink callback should avoid tearing.

Here is a small snippet of the relevant code (full code below):

```objectivec
- (void)draw:(CAMetalLayer*)metalLayer {
    if (prevDrawable) {
        [prevDrawable present];
        [prevDrawable autorelease];
    }

    /* drawable = ... render the current frame ... */

    [commandBuffer commit];
    [commandBuffer waitUntilScheduled];

    prevDrawable = [drawable retain];
}
```

My question is: Why does implementing double buffering this way still result in tearing artifacts? And is there a way to stop the tearing?

##### Environment Details

- macOS 11.5.2
- MacBook 2014
- Intel Iris Pro Integrated GPU
- No external display attached

### Full Test Project

`main.m`:

```objectivec
#import <MetalKit/MetalKit.h>
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "AAPLShaderTypes.h"

@interface Renderer : NSObject
{
    @public
    float mouseX, mouseY;
}
@end
@implementation Renderer
{
    id<MTLDevice> _device;
    id<MTLRenderPipelineState> _pipelineState;
    id<MTLCommandQueue> _commandQueue;
    vector_uint2 _viewportSize;
    id<MTLDrawable> prevDrawable;
}
- (id)initWithDevice:(id<MTLDevice>)device frame:(NSRect)frame {
    _device = device;
    _viewportSize.x = frame.size.width;
    _viewportSize.y = frame.size.height;
    mouseX = 0;
    mouseY = 0;

    NSError *error;

    id<MTLLibrary> defaultLibrary = [_device newLibraryWithFile:@"AAPLShaders.metallib"
                                                          error:&error];
    id<MTLFunction> vertexFunction = [defaultLibrary newFunctionWithName:@"vertexShader"];
    id<MTLFunction> fragmentFunction = [defaultLibrary newFunctionWithName:@"fragmentShader"];

    MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor *pipelineStateDescriptor = [[MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor alloc] init];
    pipelineStateDescriptor.label = @"Simple Pipeline";
    pipelineStateDescriptor.vertexFunction = vertexFunction;
    pipelineStateDescriptor.fragmentFunction = fragmentFunction;
    pipelineStateDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].pixelFormat = MTLPixelFormatRGBA8Unorm;

    _pipelineState = [_device newRenderPipelineStateWithDescriptor:pipelineStateDescriptor
                                                             error:&error];

    NSAssert(_pipelineState, @"Failed to create pipeline state: %@", error);

    _commandQueue = [_device newCommandQueue];

    return self;
}
- (void)draw:(CAMetalLayer*)metalLayer {
    if (prevDrawable) {
        [prevDrawable present];
        [prevDrawable autorelease];
    }

    const float size = 400;
    const float sizehalf = size/2;

    float xoff = (float)_viewportSize.x/2;
    float yoff = (float)_viewportSize.y/2;

    AAPLVertex triangleVertices[] = {
        // 2D positions,                                                    RGBA colors
        { { -xoff +        0 + self->mouseX, -yoff +    0 + self->mouseY }, { 1, 0, 0, 1 } },
        { { -xoff +     size + self->mouseX, -yoff +    0 + self->mouseY }, { 0, 1, 0, 1 } },
        { { -xoff + sizehalf + self->mouseX, -yoff + size + self->mouseY }, { 0, 0, 1, 1 } },
    };

    id<MTLCommandBuffer> commandBuffer = [_commandQueue commandBuffer];
    commandBuffer.label = @"MyCommand";
    id<CAMetalDrawable> drawable = [metalLayer nextDrawable];
    MTLRenderPassDescriptor *renderPassDescriptor = [MTLRenderPassDescriptor renderPassDescriptor];
    renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].texture = drawable.texture;
    renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].loadAction = MTLLoadActionClear;
    renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].clearColor = MTLClearColorMake(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);

    if(renderPassDescriptor != nil)
    {
        id<MTLRenderCommandEncoder> renderEncoder =
        [commandBuffer renderCommandEncoderWithDescriptor:renderPassDescriptor];
        renderEncoder.label = @"MyRenderEncoder";
        [renderEncoder setViewport:(MTLViewport){0.0, 0.0, _viewportSize.x, _viewportSize.y, 0.0, 1.0 }];
        [renderEncoder setRenderPipelineState:_pipelineState];
        [renderEncoder setVertexBytes:triangleVertices
                               length:sizeof(triangleVertices)
                              atIndex:AAPLVertexInputIndexVertices];

        [renderEncoder setVertexBytes:&_viewportSize
                               length:sizeof(_viewportSize)
                              atIndex:AAPLVertexInputIndexViewportSize];

        [renderEncoder drawPrimitives:MTLPrimitiveTypeTriangle
                          vertexStart:0
                          vertexCount:3];

        [renderEncoder endEncoding];
    }

    [commandBuffer commit];
    [commandBuffer waitUntilScheduled];

    prevDrawable = [drawable retain];
}
@end

@interface MouseFollower : NSView
@end
@implementation MouseFollower
{
    NSTrackingArea* trackingArea;
    Renderer* renderer;
}
- (void)mouseMoved:(NSEvent *)event {
    [super mouseMoved:event];
    NSPoint loc = [event locationInWindow];
    self->renderer->mouseX = loc.x * 2;
    self->renderer->mouseY = loc.y * 2;
}
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame {
    [super initWithFrame:frame];
    frame.size.width *= 2;
    frame.size.height *= 2;

    id<MTLDevice> device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice();
    CAMetalLayer* layer = [CAMetalLayer layer];

    [layer setDisplaySyncEnabled:NO];
    [layer setDevice:device];
    [layer setDrawableSize:frame.size];
    [layer setMaximumDrawableCount:3];

    [self setLayer:layer];
    [self setWantsLayer:YES];

    renderer = [[Renderer alloc] initWithDevice:device frame:frame];

    return self;
}
- (void)updateTrackingAreas {
    if (trackingArea != nil) {
        [self removeTrackingArea:trackingArea];
    }

    NSTrackingAreaOptions options =
        NSTrackingMouseEnteredAndExited |
        NSTrackingMouseMoved |
        NSTrackingActiveInKeyWindow;

    trackingArea = [[NSTrackingArea alloc] initWithRect: [self bounds]
                                                options: options
                                                  owner: self
                                               userInfo: nil];

    [self addTrackingArea:trackingArea];
}
- (void)draw {
    // Run on main thread.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        CALayer* layer = [self layer];
        @autoreleasepool {
            [renderer draw:(CAMetalLayer*)layer];
        }
    });
}
@end

CVReturn displayLinkCallback(
    CVDisplayLinkRef _displayLink,
    const CVTimeStamp* _in_now,
    const CVTimeStamp* _in_output_time,
    CVOptionFlags _flags_in,
    CVOptionFlags *_flags_out,
    void *view
) {
    [(MouseFollower*)view draw];
    return kCVReturnSuccess;
}

void setupCallback(MouseFollower* view) {
    CVDisplayLinkRef displayLink;
    CVDisplayLinkCreateWithActiveCGDisplays(&displayLink);
    CVDisplayLinkSetOutputCallback(displayLink, displayLinkCallback, view);
    CVDisplayLinkStart(displayLink);
}

@interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
    MouseFollower* innerView;
}
@end

@implementation MyAppDelegate
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [NSApp setActivationPolicy:NSApplicationActivationPolicyRegular];

    NSRect frame = NSMakeRect(400, 400, 700, 700);
    NSWindow* win = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:frame
                                                styleMask: NSWindowStyleMaskClosable
                                                            | NSWindowStyleMaskMiniaturizable
                                                            | NSWindowStyleMaskResizable
                                                            | NSWindowStyleMaskTitled
                                                  backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered
                                                    defer:NO];

    MouseFollower* view = [[MouseFollower alloc] initWithFrame:[[win contentView] frame]];
    setupCallback(view);

    [[win contentView] addSubview:view];
    [win makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
    [NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
}
@end

int main() {
    [NSApplication sharedApplication];
    MyAppDelegate* delegate = [MyAppDelegate new];
    [NSApp setDelegate:delegate];
    [NSApp run];
}
```

`Makefile`:

```
LDFLAGS := -framework Cocoa -framework MetalKit -framework quartzcore \
           -framework Metal -framework CoreVideo
CFLAGS := -g

run: main AAPLShaders.metallib
    ./main

AAPLShaders.metallib: AAPLShaders.metal
    xcrun -sdk macosx metal -c $^ -o AAPLShaders.air
    xcrun -sdk macosx metallib AAPLShaders.air -o $@

main: main.o

clean:
    rm main *.o *.air *.metallib

.PHONY: clean run
```

`AAPLShaderTypes.h`

```objectivec
/*
See LICENSE folder for this sample’s licensing information.

Abstract:
Header containing types and enum constants shared between Metal shaders and C/ObjC source
*/

#ifndef AAPLShaderTypes_h
#define AAPLShaderTypes_h

#include <simd/simd.h>

// Buffer index values shared between shader and C code to ensure Metal shader buffer inputs
// match Metal API buffer set calls.
typedef enum AAPLVertexInputIndex
{
    AAPLVertexInputIndexVertices     = 0,
    AAPLVertexInputIndexViewportSize = 1,
} AAPLVertexInputIndex;

//  This structure defines the layout of vertices sent to the vertex
//  shader. This header is shared between the .metal shader and C code, to guarantee that
//  the layout of the vertex array in the C code matches the layout that the .metal
//  vertex shader expects.
typedef struct
{
    vector_float2 position;
    vector_float4 color;
} AAPLVertex;

#endif /* AAPLShaderTypes_h */
```

`AAPLShaders.metal`

```
/*
See LICENSE folder for this sample’s licensing information.

Abstract:
Metal shaders used for this sample
*/

#include <metal_stdlib>

using namespace metal;

// Include header shared between this Metal shader code and C code executing Metal API commands.
#include "AAPLShaderTypes.h"

// Vertex shader outputs and fragment shader inputs
struct RasterizerData
{
    // The [[position]] attribute of this member indicates that this value
    // is the clip space position of the vertex when this structure is
    // returned from the vertex function.
    float4 position [[position]];

    // Since this member does not have a special attribute, the rasterizer
    // interpolates its value with the values of the other triangle vertices
    // and then passes the interpolated value to the fragment shader for each
    // fragment in the triangle.
    float4 color;
};

vertex RasterizerData
vertexShader(uint vertexID [[vertex_id]],
             constant AAPLVertex *vertices [[buffer(AAPLVertexInputIndexVertices)]],
             constant vector_uint2 *viewportSizePointer [[buffer(AAPLVertexInputIndexViewportSize)]])
{
    RasterizerData out;

    // Index into the array of positions to get the current vertex.
    // The positions are specified in pixel dimensions (i.e. a value of 100
    // is 100 pixels from the origin).
    float2 pixelSpacePosition = vertices[vertexID].position.xy;

    // Get the viewport size and cast to float.
    vector_float2 viewportSize = vector_float2(*viewportSizePointer);
    

    // To convert from positions in pixel space to positions in clip-space,
    //  divide the pixel coordinates by half the size of the viewport.
    out.position = vector_float4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    out.position.xy = pixelSpacePosition / (viewportSize / 2.0);

    // Pass the input color directly to the rasterizer.
    out.color = vertices[vertexID].color;

    return out;
}

fragment float4 fragmentShader(RasterizerData in [[stage_in]])
{
    // Return the interpolated color.
    return in.color;
}
```